# egrep the line ended with

Tags: regex, linux

```
$ cat file
c f t e, u y r s p  I y
p A w p d. R i
G e w o a l n o v s.
P G e a o c f s p
k e i c w a p p e.

$ od -c file
0000000   c       f       t       e   ,       u       y       r       s
0000020       p           I       y  \r  \n   p       A       w       p
0000040       d   .       R       i  \r  \n   G       e       w       o
0000060       a       l       n       o       v       s   .  \r  \n   P
0000100       G       e       a       o       c       f       s       p
0000120  \r  \n   k       e       i       c       w       a       p
0000140   p       e   .  \r  \n
0000146
```

I tried to use the egrep command to grep all lines ended with .
However, I was not able to do it!

for example:

```
$ egrep '.*\.' file
p A w p d. R i
G e w o a l n o v s.
k e i c w a p p e.
```

It did not give me the correct output!

Also tried to use $ to anchor the dot, \r, and \n, none of them work.
Any suggestions will help.

Answer (score 0):

You should begin converting your file in Unix format:

```
dos2unix file
```

Then you can simply use this instruction:

```
egrep "[.]$" file
```

Answer (score -1):

Your file is in DOS format (with carriage return / line feed endings). Either convert it to unix format first and use

```
egrep '\.$'
```

or leave the file unchanged and search for a literal carriage return

```
egrep $'\\.\r$'
```

(using bash trickery because grep doesn't understand `\r`).

`egrep '.*\.'` just finds all lines that contain a `.` anywhere.

Comment: Maybe spell out that `$'...'` is specifically *Bash* shell trickery.